# Return Data from Deep Link or Dynamic to Flutter App

Tags: flutter, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, plaid

I have an app where i'm looking to embed a deep / dynamic link that will route a user to the Plaid Link flow for adding financial accounts. At the end of the Plaid Link flow it should return data to my app so that i may persist the data and the user can continue in using the app. Plaid does not currently have an official Flutter Plugin.

I have not used deep links before so i am wondering if this will even work, and if so, how this might could be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that doesn't have an official Flutter plugin but there are community ones that are quite good -- I recommend checking out [Plaid Flutter](https://github.com/jorgefspereira/plaid_flutter), for example, and seeing if it solves your problem.